# If I assign dynamically created values to objects in my database is it possible to access using a fetch command to access the value?

Tags: javascript, json, object, fetch

I have a JSON file with an array of objects. One of the key values in the objects is being created dynamically. In the file it looks something like this for each object

```
id: "";
```

I then assign the id of each object based on it's index in the array. Then, I am using the id in a variable that is attached to the url to fetch data from the json file

```
let url = `/api/movies/${some-variable}`;
```

When I `console.log` the url it returns the correct string in place of the variable: `http://localhost:1313/api/movies/12`

The problem is I am getting a 404 (Not Found) error. I understand that this is because the object doesn't have an id in the JSON file when it goes to search for it.

My question is how can I assign dynamically created values to objects in my database that can be accessed using a fetch command?

Comment: Take the URL and paste it into a browser. If you still get a 404, then the issue isn't your JS code.

Comment: If you are getting a 404 error on an URL that you expect to work, it's an issue with the server